# SLF4J isDebugEnabled sometimes returns true when not enabled

Tags: java, slf4j, websphere-6.1

I'm having an intermittent problem  with `isDebugEnabled` returning true even when it's not enabled. It's on a clustered WAS 6.1 environment. The issue is exposing a NPE in spring modules validation 0.9 ([bug report](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/MOD-466)).  I can try and recompile the validation jar but would rather get to the root of the problem. I've checked the admin console for the server but there are no runtime debug settings enabled. Why would this be happening?

Comment: How intermittent? It starts and stops for no reason, or it happens on some starts of the application/server but not others? Are the slf4j jars deployed in the application, or shared libraries?

Comment: Jars are deployed with the app, some days I get the error, others not - no correlation with restarts.

Comment: Sorry, so once it starts occurring, does it continue forever? Until an application or server restart? For some unpredictable amount of time? To all cluster members at once, or only some? Anything else you can think of to help isolate.